# how to make MYSQL select query for one to many for this case?

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

```
create table person {
  id int,
  name char(10),
  primary key(id),
}


create table person_child {
  id int,
  name char(10),
  primary key(id),
  foreign key(id) references person(id));
}
```

Can a person have 1...n child so it is one to many child . my query is to find the name of person with number of child he/she have?
what will be the select statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use join and group by

```
select person.name, count(*) as num_of_child
from person 
inner join person_child on person.name = person_child.name
group by person.name;
```

Comment: thanks .i was thinking the same keyword but just confused:P thanks

Comment: please can u explain how it worked does it count first or group by first .sorry new player

Comment: Ye, of course ,, the query perform a join  .. so is created a set where all the person rows are related to person_child rows .. on this set of rows .. the group by lead the count(*) to count the number of rows for each person.name .. .. i hope is clear  .. otherwise  .. ask me again

Comment: thanks.few doubt                                                                                      1.does count = group by +sum                                                                    2.when group by is performed does that creates a different set ?is that set  information is stored somewhere ?how count get to know how many rows are there .as when i do simple select on group by with no count it doesnt show the group of set it shows only one value

Comment: I thibk a question by time is better .. question 2 .. the sets are dinamically and automatically manage by the database engine and are not available for end user .. are internal operation .. the programmer dont'have to worry for this  ..repeat the other question one by time

Comment: thank you so much that helped:). the first question is solved now .thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Select p.name,count(PC.id) from person as p Inner join person_child as PC on p.ID=PC.ID Group by p.name
This would do it

Comment: I have edited the answer.There were some typos ,did you try the above?

Comment: You person_child has ID as both primay key and foreign key...that's the problem

Comment: sorry was in a hurry .